# How to add Progress Indicator on Cards while tap in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using Cards in Flutter and want Progress Indicator at the left bottom position for 2 seconds while Tap on the card so that another page load successfully.
Does anyone know how to add?

```
 Container(
           height: 130,
           child: Card(
             child: Row(
               children: <Widget>[
                 Expanded(
                   child: ListTile(
                       title: Text(
                         'My card Location',
                         style: TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                       ),

                       leading: Icon(Icons.setting),
                       // color: Colors.blueAccent, size: mediumIconSize),
                       trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                       selected: true,

                       onTap: () async {

                    //   I try this one but not working
                         //  Flushbar(
                    // 
                       //    showProgressIndicator: true,
                       //    duration:  Duration(seconds: 2),
                       //  );
               getDetails().then((myCardlocations) {
                 Navigator
                     .of(context)
                     .pushNamed('/myCardlocations',
                     arguments: ObjectLocations(locations, 'myCardlocations'));
               }
               );
                       }
                      
                  
                   ),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           ),
         ),
```

Comment: Check out my answer, let me know, if that was some of your use or not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this using `Stack` and `CircularProgressIndicator`..

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 130,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 130,
            child: Card(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'My card Location',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                      leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                      // color: Colors.blueAccent, size: mediumIconSize),
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                      selected: true,
                      onTap: () async {
                        
                        setState(() {
                          isLoading = true;
                        });

                        getDetails().then((myCardLocations) {
                          setState(() {
                            isLoading = false;
                          });
                          // navigation code here
                        });

                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: isLoading
                ? Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,0,0,15),
                  child: SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                )
                : SizedBox(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

*Edit:*

Looks like I misunderstood the question a bit. Specifically, the place where to show the progress indicator. Anyways, if you get the idea, you can put the indicator at a different place as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain things, which I would like to mention before I give the actual answer.

- Read about [Flutter.delayed constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html), very useful thing to make some thing wait for a while and do the operation by providing `Duration`. Whatever you want to do after that duration, it will implement in the `callback` function

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: your_time, (){
   //it will perform this operation after that much of seconds
}));
```

- You can always show/hide a `Widget` using `bool value`, and make changes accordingly
- Use a column and Add the [LinearProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html) at the end of the `Widget`. Show/hide it based up on the data
- Also, use `MediaQuery` to give out the height. It is more efficient way of giving the dimensions according to all phone size. Like `match-parent` in `Android Studio`. Do the math accordingly, I have shown in the code also

```
Column(
  children: [
    Row(),
    bool val ? LinearProgressIndicator() : Container() // Container() is nothing but an empty widget which shows nothing
  ]
)
```

**Some heads up:** I have not used `getData`, since it is not defined properly but you can call it the in function which I will show you in the code, that is `pageTransit()`. Follow the comments and you are good to go

```
 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // this takes care of the show/hide of your progress indicator
  bool _showProgress = false;
  
  // this takes care of the operation
  void pageTransit(){
    // first show when the ListTile is clicked
    setState(() => _showProgress = true);
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
      // hide it after 2 seconds
      setState(() => _showProgress = false);
      
      // do the page trnasition here
      //getDetails().then((myCardlocations) {
        //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/myCardlocations',
          //arguments: ObjectLocations(locations, 'myCardlocations'));
       //}
    });  
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
         child: Card(
           child: Column(
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
             children: [
               // use your items here, based upon the bool value show hide your 
               // progress indicator
               Row(
                 children: <Widget>[
                   Expanded(
                     child: ListTile(
                         title: Text(
                           'My card Location',
                           style: TextStyle(
                               fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                         ),                       
                         leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                         // color: Colors.blueAccent, size: mediumIconSize),
                         trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                         selected: true,
                         onTap: () => pageTransit() 
                     )
                   )
                 ]
               ),
               // show/hide in the card
               _showProgress ? LinearProgressIndicator() : Container()
             ]
           )
         )
       )
    );
  }
}
```

**Result**

*Look at the `ProgressIndicator`, it remains there for 2 seconds, and then goes away*

[image: Result GIF]

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You need to define a `GlobalKey` for the `Scaffold` so that you can use a `SnackBar` (you can define the `GloablKey` in your page's `State`).

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

**2.** You need to set the key for the `Scaffold`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
...
```

**3.** You need to wrap the `Card` with a `GestureDetector` and set the `onTap` function to call `showLoading` which shows a `SnackBar` on the bottom of the screen. Call your `getDetails` function in the `showLoading`. Full code (except the define key step):

```
void _showLoading() {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 2),
      content: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new CircularProgressIndicator(),
          new Text("Loading...")
        ],
      ),
    ));
    // call to your getDetails and its steps should be here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My app"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Card(
                child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              'My card Location',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                            ),

                            leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                            // color: Colors.blueAccent, size: mediumIconSize),
                            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                            selected: true,
                      )),
            ])),
        onTap: () => _showLoading(),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:** you can also style the `SnackBar`.

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: oh okay, I get it now. So the OP meant to show an indicator at left bottom of page. Stupid of me, I wrote an answer to show an indicator at left bottom of the `Card` lol. I think I'll make a note of this in my answer. :D

Comment: It's ok, it might still be helpful for someone facing the same problem later on. @JigarPatel